# Difference between "a" and "a:link"

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the difference between `a` and `a:link`, and when do I use one over the other?

Comment: I'd recommend always using the former, by the way.

Comment: @minitech: Be careful with specificity - classes and pseudo-classes are equal, which may be good or bad depending on how you write your selectors. I generally make it a point to use it for styles I know won't change in any of the other link states, and use overrides only when necessary. For example, certain font styles, or something more advanced - transitions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`a:link` is specifically for links that have not been visited. `a` applies to all `<a>` elements.

Comment: "links" for the purposes of `:link` and `:visited` are defined in HTML 4 as `<a>` elements with a `href` attribute. In other words, `a:link, a:visited` matches exactly the same elements as `a[href]`, whereas `a` matches any elements regardless of whether the attribute is present. This definition is informatively mentioned in [the CSS2.1 selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes).

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure about that so I didn't include it in my answer. Thank you for sharing. That's good to know.

Comment: :link specifies anchor elements whose targets (href attribute) have not been visited. :visited targets anchor elements whose targets have been visited. :link and :visited are mutually exclusive;

Answer (score 4):

John Conde’s answer and comments to it describe well the meanings of the selectors, but to address the question as asked I think we need to add these:

The selector `a:link` is more specific than `a`. This is evident when you think about it, but it might be missed when considering the effects of several CSS rules that apply to an element.

If you want to set properties on links in general (e.g., the font face of links), using `a` is simplest *if* you can ensure that `a` elements without `href` attributes do not appear. (It has been common to set destinations for links using `a` elements with a `name` attribute, normally without an `href` attribute; the more modern approach is to use the `id` attribute on any suitable element.)

But in most cases, it is best to use both `:link` and `:visited`, to avoid the risk of styling `a` elements that are not links. You would then use `:link, :visited {...}` to set properties for all links and `:link {...}` and `:visited {...}` to set properties for unvisited links and for visited links separately (typically, different colors for them).

The difference between `:link` and `a:link`, apart from specificity, is that `:link` covers elements that are classified as links. Although currently only `a` elements can create links, this might change in a future version of HTML.

Comment: Your answer inspired me to write up something in even greater detail :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587245/is-there-a-reason-to-use-a-instead-of-alink-or-avisited-in-my-stylesheet/10589840#10589840