# Is there a reason to use a instead of a:link or a:visited in my stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Can anyone tell me if there's any reason to use `a {}` instead of (or adjacent to) `a:link, a:visited {}` in my stylesheet?  I've had inconsistent results testing this across browsers, sites, etc, so I've never come up with a satisfactory answer.  I was not able to find an answer on The Google, either.

This is of course assuming there would **never** be a reason to use an `<a>` tag without an `href` value. Maybe that's a mistaken assumption.

** **EDIT** **

I know what these selectors *do*. I'm looking for reasons why I would use `a` instead of `a:link` or `a:visited`, since `a` always has an `href` attribute. But as Chris Blake and Ryan P said in the answers, there is also `<a name="top">` and javascript usage, neither of which would need the `href` attribute.

Comment: Related: [Difference between "a" and "a:link"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360295/difference-between-a-and-alink) (Jukka K. Korpela offers some [great insight](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10361178/106224), on which I go on to elaborate in my answer which I've just posted here)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> This is of course assuming there would **never** be a reason to use an `<a>` tag without an `href` value. Maybe that's a mistaken assumption.

It depends on your project. Strictly speaking, that *is* a mistaken assumption, as not every `<a>` element needs to have a `href` attribute. Indeed, it's still not **required** in HTML5 to specify `href` for every `<a>`. [Chris Blake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587245/is-there-a-reason-to-use-a-instead-of-alink-or-avisited-in-my-stylesheet/10587315#10587315) and [Ryan P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587245/is-there-a-reason-to-use-a-instead-of-alink-or-avisited-in-my-stylesheet/10587325#10587325) mention named anchors, and I'll add that while the `name` attribute for `<a>` has been [made obsolete as of HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features), named anchors are still rife and will continue to be, simply by legacy and tradition.

That said, **going forward**, authors are recommended to use `id` attributes and not named anchors to designate document anchor fragments.

Also, `<a>` elements that lack `href` attributes but have `onclick` attributes for JavaScript are a mess. Even if you insist on using `onclick` to bind events, for the sake of graceful degradation you should at least point it *somewhere* using `href`.

But to make things simple, let's assume that you won't be writing `<a>` elements without `href` attributes.

With this in mind, going back to the CSS selectors, there are two important points to consider:

### Are they the same?

No, the selectors `a` and `a:link, a:visited` are not strictly equivalent. I'll quote a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367403/link-styling-behaviour-in-ie6/9367665#9367665) of mine on this topic:

> The selector `a` should match any `<a>` elements, while `a:link` only matches `<a>` elements that are *unvisited hyperlinks* (the HTML 4 document type defines hyperlinks as `<a>` elements with a `href` attribute). Nowhere does it state in either specification that `a` should automatically translate to `a:link` or vice versa.

In other words, in HTML, `a:link, a:visited` (in CSS1) is strictly equivalent to `a[href]` (in CSS2 with an attribute selector) or `a:any-link` (new in [Selectors level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#the-any-link-pseudo)), rather than `a`. Note that it doesn't matter whether the attribute has a value or not, as long as it is present the pseudo-classes will match, hence `[href]`. Note also that this is true for all current standards of HTML, and I believe this includes HTML5, since as mentioned above `href` is not a required attribute in any existing spec.

Just bear in mind, that other languages may define completely different semantics for `:link` and `:visited` — it just so happens that they coincide with an equally specific selector in HTML, which is covered next...

### Specificity

This is a huge gotcha: `a` is less specific than either `a:link` or `a:visited`, which is a very common source of specificity problems that are particularly evident when applying styles to `a`, `a:link` and `a:visited` separately. This then leads to all kinds of `!important` hacks to get around a lack of understanding of specificity.

For example, consider this CSS:

```css
/* All unvisited links should be red */
a:link {
    color: red;
}

/* All visited links should be slightly darker */
a:visited {
    color: maroon;
}

/* But no matter what, header links must be white at all times! */
body > header > a {
    color: white;
}
```

This doesn't work as expected, because `a:link` and `a:visited` (what I call generalized rules/selectors) are more specific than `body > header > a` (what I call a specialized rule/selector), so header links will in fact **never** be white:

```css
/* 1 pseudo-class, 1 type  -> specificity = (0,1,1) */
a:link, a:visited

/* 3 types                 -> specificity = (0,0,3) */
body > header > a
```

Now the first thing that comes to mind for most CSS coders is to throw in `!important`, trumping specificity altogether:

```css
body > header > a {
    color: white !important;
}
```

But that gets you all kinds of bad rep, right? So let's not do that.

Selectors level 4 gives you not one, but *two* solutions to this specificity problem. These solutions, new as they are, aren't supported in Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge Legacy (the UWP/EdgeHTML/not-Chromium one), but thankfully there is a third solution that works in Internet Explorer 7 and later, which is `a[href]`, the attribute selector I mentioned above.

#### 1. The `:any-link` pseudo-class

`:any-link` has some history behind it which you can read in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436526/whats-the-any-link-pseudo-class-for/14437502#14437502), but practically speaking, `:any-link` serves as a catch-all for `:link, :visited`. Its main purpose is to eliminate selector duplication, and for that reason there is in fact an equivalent in the form of `:is(:link, :visited)`.

You can use `a:any-link` in your specialized rule to match the specificity of the generalized `a:link` and `a:visited` rules, thereby allowing it to override them:

```css
a:link {
    color: red;
}

a:visited {
    color: maroon;
}

/* 1 pseudo-class, 3 types -> specificity = (0,1,3) */
body > header > a:any-link {
    color: white;
}
```

#### 2. The `:where()` pseudo-class

`:where()` also has some history behind it, but essentially it's an analogue to `:is()` with the exception that it zeroes out the specificity of its argument. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433247/what-is-the-difference-between-where-and-is/67450559#67450559) for an in-depth guide to how it works.

You can wrap the `:link` and `:visited` pseudo-classes in `:where()`s to remove their pseudo-class specificity, thereby allowing them to be overridden by the specialized rule:

```css
/* 1 type                  -> specificity = (0,0,1) */
a:where(:link) {
    color: red;
}

/* 1 type                  -> specificity = (0,0,1) */
a:where(:visited) {
    color: maroon;
}

/* 3 types                 -> specificity = (0,0,3) */
body > header > a {
    color: white;
}
```

#### 3. `a[href]` (for older browsers)

Fortunately, if you need to support older browsers, an attribute selector is as specific as a pseudo-class. This means you can use `a[href]` to mean both/either `a:link` and/or `a:visited`, and not run into specificity issues because they are equally specific!

```css
/* 1 attribute, 3 types    -> specificity = (0,1,3) */
body > header > a[href] {
    color: white;
}
```

### So which selector(s) to use?

This is all still incredibly subjective, but I follow these personal rules of thumb:

- Apply to `a` styles that *do not depend on the state of a link* (i.e. as long as it's a link will do).
- Apply to `a:link` and `a:visited` styles where it *does matter* whether a link is visited or not.
- Taking into account the specificity problems mentioned above, do not mix any declarations between *both* `a` and `a:link`/`a:visited` rules. If I need to apply the same property to both states somewhere, but I already have it in separate `a:link` and `a:visited` rules, I'll use one of the 3 options above to avoid specificity problems.

For example, here are the link styles I used in my site's Coming Soon page prior to its launch:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: text-shadow 0.15s linear;
}

a:link {
    color: rgb(119, 255, 221);
}

a:visited {
    color: rgb(68, 204, 170);
}

a:hover, a:active {
    text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em currentColor;
}

a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}

/* ... */

footer a:link, footer a:visited {
    color: rgb(71, 173, 153);
}
```

The `text-shadow` transition is defined for all `a` elements, regardless of whether they are visited or not, because the transition only takes effect when one of them is moused over and clicked (corresponding to the `a:hover, a:active` rule).

Now, I want visited links to have a slightly darker shade than unvisited links, so I put the colors in separate `a:link` and `a:visited` rules. However, for some reason, I want footer links to appear the same color whether they're visited or not.

If I use `footer a`, I'll run into the specificity problems described above, so I choose `footer a:link, footer a:visited` instead. This was for legacy reasons (as you'll see below, I originally posted this in 2012!), but of course it can be shortened to `footer a:any-link`. However, the specificity-matching principle applies all the same.

Hopefully my advice helps you get a handle on the mess that is link styles.

Comment: So 2 questions. a) Is it outdated/wrong to say I can't style `a:hover` until I style `a:link` and b) does `a[href]` work on any modern browser (ffx,webkit,IE>7,etc)?

Comment: a) You only need to make sure to place `a:hover` after `a:link` and `a:visited`, if you use the pseudo-classes. Again, specificity issues (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371732/why-does-foo-alink-foo-avisited-selector-override-ahover-aactive-s/7371846#7371846)) b) All of them support it including IE7+.

Answer (score 3):

The `a:link` and `a:visited` are used to specify *custom* (other than browser default) colors for normal and visited links respectively whereas `a {}` is used to overwrite all styles including `a:link`, `a:visited`, `a:active`. For example following will have same color irrespective of whether link is active, visited or not or hovered upon:

```
a { color:red; }
```

You can avoid that by using individual styles eg `a:pseudoClass` notation.

Comment: Note that `a` never overrides pseudo-classes by itself. Instead, the pseudo-classes override it once you specify them.

Answer (score 3):

Well you could have an anchor that is *just* an anchor.  For example,

```
<a href="#top">Return to top</a>

<a name="top">Top</a>
```

Which corrects your false assumption (albeit, an anchor isn't needed for the "top", but it's the most philosophically correct).

In addition, as Sarfraz said, `a {}` overrides all occurrences of other `a:` style properties if styled (and assuming the `a {}` is after the other `a:` declarations).

Comment: not related to this question: `#top` exists even w/o specifically declaring it?? I never knew that!

Comment: @JakeParis `#top` was declared, in `<a name="top">`. The behavior of hash jumping to blocks with a given `id` is a newer behavior.

Comment: Right.  Jump to by name was the official (and perhaps old-school now?) method of hash jumping before HTML4, I think it was.

Answer (score 3):

`a:link` and `a:visited` have specific meanings. `a` by itself will affect all `<a>` elements whereas `a:link` will only affect links that have not yet been visited and `a:visited` will only affect links that have been visited.

Answer (score 3):

There are two cases where an `a` may not have an `href` property. The first is regular anchors (i.e. `<a name="someplace" />`) and the second is pure Javascript interaction (i.e. `<a onclick="doSomething( );" />`). Those are not 'links' and shouldn't be styled the same.

EDIT: To clarify, `a:link` is pretty much equivalent to `a[href]` (I believe the former notation existed before the attribute selectors were available or standardized). So a reason to use `a` instead of `a:link` would be if you wanted all anchor tags styled the same. The default styles in some browsers display the two differently - such as underlines only applied to `a:link` and not to `a`.

Comment: The strict equivalent of `a[href]` is actually `a:link, a:visited`. One represents unvisited links, the other visited. And indeed, some browsers (like older versions of IE) have inconsistencies with applying styles to `a` elements depending on whether the pseudo-classes are used or not.

Comment: Also, yes, `:link` and `:visited` are part of CSS1 (the very first pseudo-classes), while attribute selectors were introduced in CSS2.