# CSS selector a:link:hover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm trying to create my website so you can tell where you are just by the colour of the elements in each div. The website is only one page and I'm using jQuery to slide out sections of the website when you click to open that section (As opposed to having seperate .html's).

To show them which section they have open I'm making all links in each section the same colour as the text that opens that section. However I also want to have`<a> </a>` tags which aren't links to add a bit of colour to the site and to attract viewers to key bits of information. For this reason I want to only apply link effects to `<a> </a>` tags which are actually links... So I've tried this:

```css
#box1 a{
    color: #68cff2;
}

#box1 a:link:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #68cff2;
}
```

This works for the background-color as in it only changes the background colour for `<a> </a>`'s that have a href="..." but it doesn't change the color of the font for such links... is there any way to sort this?

Comment: If it doesn't change the font color, you probably have something with higher specificity overriding the color. Also, you may need to repeat the selector for visited links: `#box1 a:link:hover, #box1 a:visited:hover` (or just use `#box1 a[href]:hover` instead, [more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587245/is-there-a-reason-to-use-a-instead-of-alink-or-avisited-in-my-stylesheet/10589840#10589840)).

Comment: Those are the only styles I have selecting the colour of <a> elements for each box... :/

Comment: I've even tried using !important... doesn't work either :/

Comment: Try looking in your browser's developer tools and see what's going on in the CSS panel. You may also wish to show your HTML.

Comment: Good idea! one second...

Comment: Hmmm interestingly it works on Firefox but not safari...

Comment: Thank you very much!! Adding the `#box1 a:visited:hover` worked :)

Comment: I just noticed that you're using `<a>` to highlight key information. That's not quite appropriate. I've edited my answer to address that bit.

Comment: I'm wondering about this too - why not just use the generic `<span>` to add bits of color and other decorative stuff?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:link` pseudo-class only applies to *unvisited* links, as opposed to *all* links. Remember that you have visited links to account for as well. You may need to repeat the selector for visited links, as I notice that you haven't done so:

```css
#box1 a:link:hover, #box1 a:visited:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #68cff2;
}
```

(or just use `#box1 a[href]:hover` instead, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587245/is-there-a-reason-to-use-a-instead-of-alink-or-avisited-in-my-stylesheet/10589840#10589840))

I should add, though, that you shouldn't be using `<a>` tags to mark up things that aren't links and don't serve as anchors either, just to "add a bit of colour to the site and to attract viewers to key bits of information". That's not what they're designed for. A more semantic alternative would be something like `<em>` or `<strong>`, though of course you have to remove the italic or bold style if you don't want it:

```css
#box1 a, #box1 em {
    font-style: normal;
    color: #68cff2;
}

#box1 a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #68cff2;
}
```

Then you won't need to specify the `:link` and `:visited` pseudo-classes, since you can basically guarantee that all your remaining `<a>` elements are links.

Comment: I tried the `a[href]:hover` method as well as the simple foolish other mistake I made :P and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @simonthumper: Hmmm, weird. Well the proper *CSS* way is to use the pseudo-classes, plus you get free IE compatibility anyway so why not ;)

Answer (score 3):

Is there a need for `a:link:hover{}`?  Just try using  `a:hover {}`

Answer (score 1):

`a:hover` will also affect the anchor tags, which can be confusing to end-users if they behave in the same way as links.