# CSS Selector 'Precedence' Query

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm curious, what is the functional difference between the following snippets, if there is any? I am unsure how the ',' affects statements. Does the #page > affect link in the first eg?

```
#page > a:visited, a:link{}
```

and

```
#page > a:link{}
#page > a:visited{}
```

Comment: Related question: [Is there a reason to use a instead of a:link or a:visited in my stylesheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587245/is-there-a-reason-to-use-a-instead-of-alink-or-avisited-in-my-stylesheet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**CSS Selectors - 5. Groups of selectors**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping)
>
> A comma-separated list of selectors represents the union of all elements selected by each of the individual selectors in the list.

In other words, `#page > a:visited, a:link` represents two separate, unrelated selectors.

Therefore the following:

```
#page > a:visited,
a:link {}
```

is *not* equivalent to:

```
#page > a:link {}
#page > a:visited {}
```

You would have to group the entire selector in order to yield the same results:

```
#page > a:link,
#page > a:visited {}
```

---

On a somewhat related side note, if you were using a CSS preprocessor, such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), you could use:

```
#page > a {
    &:visited,
    &:link {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Which would compile to the following:

```
#page > a:visited,
#page > a:link {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `,` separates 2 different selectors so they have the same style definition.

No the `#page >` does not affect the selector after the `,`

This:

```
#page > a:link{}
#page > a:visited{}
```

Could be expressed as:

```
#page > a:link,#page > a:visited{}
```

If they had the exact same styles